# Javascript: returning a default value if a parameter is not called as a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, module, closures

I'd like to know how to return a default value on a variable call, let's say this variable returns an object with functions, but in case I call it directly (ie, calling module directly, not module.get) I want it to return a default value from one of it's inner functions:

Currently I have this:

```
function createModule() {    
    module = (function() {
        var val = null;

        function getVal() {
            return val;
        }

        function setVal(newVal) {
            val = newVal;
        }

        return {
            get: getVal, 
            set: setVal
        }
    })();
}
```

Currently the module returns an `object`, you can use the `get()` and `set()` parameter functions to modify its `val` variable, however I'd like the module to have a default return value to ´module´.

Is there any way that this might be achieved?

EDIT: The functionality that I want is this:

```
> module.set('testValue');

> module.get();
'testValue'

> module; // or using module(); instead
'testValue'
```

I want to give a call to `module` or `module()` to be the exact same as calling `module.get()`

Comment: your default value is null

Comment: by changing your get function to `function getVal() {return yourDefaultVal;}`

Comment: really not clear what you are wanting or what you mean by `in case I call the parameter directly`

Comment: unfortunately, the people editing this post seem to like ruining the point of the post, I'm sorry Rory, but that's not what I wanted to ask.

Comment: Either module is the `'testvalue'` *or* an object or a function, it can't be both. Why would you want that?

Comment: because I want to be able to have a default value attributed by me to an object other than having to access it's attributes, it's one of those "what if" moments that a person tends to have, and as explained below, will be used on a small personal project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `module` object a function that acts like `get`,:

```
module = (function() {
    var val = null;

    function getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    function setVal(newVal) {
        val = newVal;
    }

    function module() {
        return val;
    }
    module.get = getVal;
    moudle.set = setVal;
    return module;
})();

> module.set('testValue')
> module.get()
'testValue'
> module()
'testValue'
```

However I don't see why you would need that.

Comment: thanks, I seriously didn't even think about that!
well I'm working on a small personal framework and honestly, the less I type to get a value the better (yeah, I know, slacker), thing is, if I'm calling up a modular object in which I know that I only want to access a value that should be a default return from it, why even bother with typing the .get() instead of just directly accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
function createModule(opt) {

  var options = {
    val: 'foo'
  };


  if(typeof opt === 'object'){
    // Using underscore's extend method... jQuery has a similar method, or you can create your own.
    _.extend(options, opt);
  }

  module = (function() {
      var val = options.val;

      function getVal() {
          return val;
      }

      function setVal(newVal) {
          val = newVal;
      }

      return {
          get: getVal, 
          set: setVal
      }
  })();
}
```